# What do the use of these symbols inside the scanf statement mean?

Tags: c, scanf

The problem is in the fourth `scanf`. Please help me understand the use of `scanf("%[^\n]%*c", c)`.

```
    char a;
    char b[30];
    char c[50];
    
    scanf("%c", &a);
    scanf("%s", b);
    scanf("\n");
    
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", c);
    
    printf("%c \n", a);
    printf("%s \n", b);
    printf("%s \n", c);
    return 0;
```

Comment: This is why you need to have [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) open when learning C. See `[set]` there.

Comment: Don't try to understand `scanf()` - just don't use it. `scanf()` is perverse and has strange corner cases that can lead to undefined behavior and/or data loss.  If you're parsing text input in lines, use `fgets()` (or `getline()` if available), and then parse the text read in.

Comment: The key to using `scanf` is to understand how it handles whitespace characters, in the format string and from the input. The posted code shows a lack of that - note the `scanf("\n");` kludge to get rid of the newline that was left in the buffer. It's generally a bad idea trying to deal with *trailing* whitespace: better to deal with *leading* whitespace. That, and the kludge which the question asks about should be removed, and replaced with a leading space where needed, to filter the leading whitespace. So `scanf(" %c", &a);` and `scanf(" %[^\n]", c);` . . .

Comment: ... Some explanation: most of the format specifiers for `scanf` automatically filter leading whitespace, but `%c` and `%[]` and `%n` do not. Adding a space in front of the `%` instructs `scanf` to filter leading whitespace here too. The reason is those three specifiers allow you to read every character including whitespace, but a way is provided so they behave like `%d` and `%f` and `%s` (etc) where needed. Moreover, the leading space does not just filter *one* character - it filters *any amount* of whitespace, including none. But in the kludges, there must be exactly one whitespace character.

Answer (score 5):

`%[` matches any character found in its *set* of characters. `]` terminates the set.

- For example, with the input `hello world`, `%[ehlo]` matches `hello`, stopping when it encounters the space which is not found in the set.

Starting that set with `^` *inverts* the match, matching any character *not* found in the set.

The effect: `%[^\n]` matches as many characters as it can, that are **not** the newline character.

`%c` matches any character. Adding `*`, as in `%*c`, prevents `scanf` from assigning that character to any variable.

The overall effect is that `"%[^\n]%*c"` reads as many characters as it can, storing those characters in a buffer until it reaches a newline character. It then consumes and discards the newline. Effectively, it reads a line of text.

---

Note that not specifying a *maximum field-width* when using `%[` (or `%s`) leaves your program open to buffer overflows (same problem as [using `gets()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/2505965)).

To avoid potentially [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior), you should always provide the maximum number of characters to be read

```
char c[50];
scanf("%49[^\n]%*c", c);
```

which should be at most the size of the buffer minus one (to leave room for the null-terminating byte, `'\0'`).

In this particular example, you will experience data loss if the string entered is *longer* than 49 characters, as `%*c` will consume something other than the newline.

For these reasons, it is generally advisable to instead use [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) when you want to read a line of text, as you can more easily detect oversized lines.

Comment: Also note that `scanf("%[^\n]%*c", c);` will fail and return `0` on an empty line, which will not be consumed at all.